# CNNモデルの入力画像をNumpy配列に変換して読み込ませようとするとエラーが発生する

Tags: python, python3, keras

vgg16をファインチューニングしたCNNモデルをヒートマップとして可視化させるために、「PythonとKerasによるディープラーニング, P.182」を参考にプログラムを作成したのですが、入力画像をNumpy配列に変換して読み込ませようとするとエラーを吐いてしまいます。

以下プログラムの一部抜粋とエラー内容です。どうかご回答お願いいたします。

**コード (抜粋):**

```py
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
preds = model.predict(x)
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
----> 1 preds = model.predict(x)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps)
   1167                                             batch_size=batch_size,
   1168                                             verbose=verbose,
-> 1169                                             steps=steps)
   1170 
   1171     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in predict_loop(model, f, ins, batch_size, verbose, steps)
    292                 ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    293 
--> 294             batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    295             batch_outs = to_list(batch_outs)
    296             if batch_index == 0:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)
   2716         else:
   2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2673             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2674         else:
-> 2675             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2676         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2677 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1456         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1457                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1458                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1459         if run_metadata:
   1460           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node block1_conv1_1/convolution}}]]
  (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node block1_conv1_1/convolution}}]]
     [[sequential_2/dense_4/Softmax/_607]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Comment: 再現するか確認できるように、利用した事前学習済みモデル(例えばVGG16)と画像データのパス(img_pathを指定した方法)のコードも書いてください。

Answer (score 0):

Qiitaの [機械学習の勉強すっぞ！Keras-TensorFlowでCNN(畳み込みニューラルネットワーク)の演習をやろうとしたらエラーが出た件](https://qiita.com/minarai/items/48ab415d134e9a44f7a5)　の記事に書かれている状況と似ているように思われます。

記事に書かれている解決方法を試してみては、いかがでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

anacondaを使っていて、cuda, cudnn関連がうまく設定されていない可能性が高いです。使っているtensorflow, cuda, cudnnのバージョンが対応関係にあるか確認してからOSの環境変数の設定をチェックしてください。

- テストビルドにおける環境: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

以下のコードは私の環境で正常動作しました。

環境

- ubuntu 20.04
- tensorflow 2.8.0
- cuda 11.2
- cudnn 8.1

```py
from keras_preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

model = VGG16(weights="imagenet")
img_path = "img.jpg"
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
preds = model.predict(x)
print(preds)
```